# How to Restrict Empty rows print in page

Tags: php, html-lists

Code as been given

;`

```html
        <ul style="width:100%;font-family: calibri;font-size: 15px;">
                <?php if ($com['Candidate_PG_Qualification'])!=""?>
                  <li><?php echo $com['Candidate_PG_Qualification']."         ".$com['Candidate_PG_Specialisation']." ".$com['Candidate_PG_University']." ".$com['Candidate_PG_YOP']; ?></li>;
                <?php ?>
                <li style="line-height: 1.6em; padding:10px;color:black;"><?php echo $com['Candidate_UG_Qualification']." ".$com['Candidate_UG_Specialisation']." ".$com['Candidate_UG_University']." ".$com['Candidate_UG_YOP']; ?></li>
                <li style="line-height: 1.6em; padding:10px;color:black;"><?php echo $com['HSC_Board_of_Education']." ".$com['Candidate_HSC_YOP'];; ?></li>
                <li style="line-height: 1.6em; padding:10px;color:black;"><?php echo $com['SSLC_Board_of_Education']." ".$com['Candidate_SSLC_YOP']; ?></li>
                </ul>
```

`

Comment: Its typo error.   <?php if ($com['Candidate_PG_Qualification'])!=""?>. You closed the if tag wrongly. it should be *<?php if ($com['Candidate_PG_Qualification'] !="" ) ?>*.


You can try if($com['Candidate_PG_Qualification'] != "" &&  !empty($com['Candidate_PG_Qualification'])) {
    your condition logic here
}

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly you want but you have a code error.

Here's the fixed code:

```
<ul style="width:100%;font-family: calibri;font-size: 15px;">
    <?php if (!empty($com['Candidate_PG_Qualification'])): ?>
        <li><?php echo $com['Candidate_PG_Qualification']."         ".$com['Candidate_PG_Specialisation']." ".$com['Candidate_PG_University']." ".$com['Candidate_PG_YOP']; ?></li>;
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php if (!empty($com['Candidate_UG_Qualification'])): ?>
        <li style="line-height: 1.6em; padding:10px;color:black;"><?php echo $com['Candidate_UG_Qualification']." ".$com['Candidate_UG_Specialisation']." ".$com['Candidate_UG_University']." ".$com['Candidate_UG_YOP']; ?></li>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php if (!empty($com['HSC_Board_of_Education'])): ?>
        <li style="line-height: 1.6em; padding:10px;color:black;"><?php echo $com['HSC_Board_of_Education']." ".$com['Candidate_HSC_YOP']; ?></li>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php if (!empty($com['SSLC_Board_of_Education'])): ?>
        <li style="line-height: 1.6em; padding:10px;color:black;"><?php echo $com['SSLC_Board_of_Education']." ".$com['Candidate_SSLC_YOP']; ?></li>
    <?php endif;?>
</ul>
```

Comment: @ArumugamRajamani Okay, I edited my answer. I moved the `if statement` outside of `<ul>`

Comment: @ArumugamRajamani This should work If your don't want to print the `<ul>` list if the **Candidate_PG_Qualification** is empty. Maybe theirs some other errors in your code.

Comment: <ul style="width:100%;font-family: calibri;font-size: 15px;">
<li style="line-height: 1.6em; padding:10px;color:black;"><?php echo $com['Candidate_UG_Qualification']." ".$com['Candidate_UG_Specialisation']." ".$com['Candidate_UG_University']." ".$com['Candidate_UG_YOP']; ?></li>
<li style="line-height: 1.6em; padding:10px;color:black;"><?php echo $com['HSC_Board_of_Education']." ".$com['Candidate_HSC_YOP'];; ?></li>
<li style="line-height: 1.6em; padding:10px;color:black;"><?php echo $com['SSLC_Board_of_Education']." ".$com['Candidate_SSLC_YOP']; ?></li>
</ul>

Comment: this one is working fine

Comment: I Want To block printing if candidate_ug_qualification is empty but HSC_Board_of_Education have data need to print only **HSC_Board_of_Education**

Comment: Thanks @Bluetree its working fine